Developing Android application with Room - why is database cleared between builds?
I'm following this course on use of Room in Android development:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-update-data-room
The DB class is defined to create a new DB only if one does not already exist:
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class InventoryDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: InventoryDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): InventoryDatabase {
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, InventoryDatabase::class.java, "item_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                    .also { Instance = it }
            }
        }
    }
}

The DB version is never changed, nor are my DB, DAO, or Entity classes (which would change the schema). I presume that is what would trigger destructive migration.
Consequently, I would expect that once the DB is created, its content would persist. However, I find that when I rebuild my app and run it again, the content is (sometimes?) gone. Why would this be? Am I somehow cluttering the filesystem with DB instances (as far as I can tell, the Filesystem location Room uses by default requires root access, so I can't tell)?

If you use debug builds of your app, Android Studio Device Explorer allows to list and view your app's private data without root permissions.

Thanks, @Robert. Do you know where the default database location for Room resides?
Although this doesn't address my main question, which is about behavior of Room, I now suspect that rebuilding/running my app involves an uninstall/reinstall of the APK, and the uninstall clears the DB from the filesystem. Just a guess, though.

For the record, my guess was wrong. Martin pointed out in the answer that clearing app storage (including my DB) is a feature of Android Studio which can be configured. Thanks all.

Uncheck "clear app storage before deployment" in the run configuration.

